# Trying to define two different values for same variable in one method. rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to define two different values to the one variable inside a sessions controller. I am getting "syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif, expecting keyword_end" and "syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end". Obviously there is something wrong with elsif, or my grammar here. i am wondering what I am doing wrong or someone tell me a different way to do this.

```
def create
  unless user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])

  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    log_in user
    redirect_to user
     # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
  else
     # Create an error message.
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end 

  elsif 
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    log_in user
    redirect_to user
  end
end
```

Comment: tried this and still same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,the error occurred because you were using `elsif` with `unless` which is not correct, you can only use `else` with unless.

```
def create
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])      
  unless user.present?
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
      # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
    else
      # Create an error message.
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end    
  else        
    log_in user
    redirect_to user
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: hot darn. your right. thanks for the help. Ill have to understand how that works..

Comment: The error occurred because you were using `elsif` with `unless` which is not correct, you can only use `else` with unless, edited my answer with the explanation.

Comment: ahh ok. i dont understand the grammar why it does not as user.present? is asking if the user is present i thought already was?