# Distinguishing between User and user in rails when getting a user from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

This is my sessions controller. I changed a line of code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40448494/trying-to-define-two-different-values-for-same-variable-in-one-method-rails) and I am just a bit uncertain why it is the way it is.

I have looked in to the definition of classes and done alot of researching trying to find out why `unless user.present?` is not a capital U. E.g.`unless User.present?`

If it is of the User class then it should be User to be searched for in the database as `User.find_by` is.

Does rails first look into the database that reads User as user, lowercase.

I say this because the line of code before it also uses `user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])` and User is also capitalised, so how can rails distinguish between the twolines of code that are both of the User class?

```
def create
   user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])

  unless user.present?
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
     if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    log_in user
    redirect_to user_url(user)
  # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
    else
     # Create an error message.
     flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end    
  else        
    log_in user
    redirect_to user_url(user)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
```

you are defining a variable `user`, which is used later on in your controller.

So, when you then write:

```
unless user.present?
```

You are really writing:

```
unless User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"]).present?
```

The line `User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])` is getting the User from the database, storing it inside the `user` variable, and checking whether a User is present

Also, in your `unless` statement, you are defining a `user` variable so it can be used in a different manner than the original `user` variable in line 2

Capitalisation in ruby (and most languages) will mean different things. For example, if you had 3 variables: `User`, `user` and `USER` they are all different. Ruby can distinguish between the three, just like in your method.

Comment: ahh ok, i totally get it now. thanks for the help, and editing my post :) I think by the variables you mean constants if they are uppercase in anyway.